# Good MVC projects

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm thinking of building a small web app using the MVC framework as a way to introduce myself to it. The idea of a project to get myself started is a small gambling monitoring piece of software that I can enter a a list of all my small bets I have along with other friends. Some of the things I hope to capture using this web app is:
- log bets
- Enter team wins-draws-losses
- PnL on bets
- comparison between friends
so I think theres quite a bit of scope.

My experience is some c# asp.net winforms dev and I have more of a sql server backend development background in TSQL.

I just wondered what was people's experience in testing the waters with asp.net mvc and if my project is at the right level...or am I in a bit over my head?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suggest you to read  Rob Conery's [MVC Storefront Series](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/mvc-storefront-part-1/)

Answer (score 3):

The app most people appear to go to first is a blog - the new Hello World. They're simple enough while giving you a fairly good introduction to several concepts that change between framework styles.

I probably wouldn't jump feet-first into it with an untested app. If you've already designed and written it, porting it might be okay, but if you haven't, there might be a few too many unknowns and you might get lost.

But that's just my stance. If you have enough determination to figure out the way your app is supposed to work at the same time as the framework does - that's fine too. Whatever suits you best.

Comment: I agree creating some sort of blog software is a great place to start.

Answer (score 2):

[Kigg](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/KiggBuildingADiggCloneWithASPNETMVC1.aspx) might be intersting to have a look at. 
It's a digg clone in MVC.